# Python-Requests full URL from error message

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to unshorten URLs with the requests library. I'm currently doing something like this:

```
import requests
from contextlib import closing

def unshorten(url):
    session = requests.session()
    with closing(session.head(url)) as req:
        r = req
    if not r.headers.get('location'):  # not a redirect
        return url
    tmp_url = url
    try:
        for redir in session.resolve_redirects(r, r.request):
            if redir.status_code == 200 and not url_no_good(redir.url):  # ok!
                return redir.url
            else:
                tmp_url = redir.url
        else: # no acceptable responses :(
            return tmp_url
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        return url
```

(url_no_good is shorthand for some tests to make sure the url isn't, e.g., a DNS-mediated 404 page)

I'm running into a problem where a given url redirects to a no-longer-valid site. I don't want the shortened link, I want the 'bad' url. I 'solved' this with

```
ERR_PAT = re.compile(r'host=\'([\w\d\.]+)\'')
...
        try:
            for redir in session.resolve_redirects(r, r.request):
            ...
        except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
            return url
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            return 'http://' + re.search(ERR_PAT, e.message.message).group(1) + e.message.url
```

since, for a requests ConnectionError, `err.message.message` is the string representation of the error and `err.message.url` is the non-domain part of the url, e.g., `/foo/bar?baz=bloo`. Cobbling together the different parts of the error message like this feels *incredibly* hacky, and I'm really curious if there's a less-involved way of handling this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

When that exception is raised, `redir` is still bound to the last request that you tried to follow the redirect on:

```
try:
    redir = r  # in case the first redirect fails
    for redir in session.resolve_redirects(r, r.request):
        if redir.status_code == 200 and not url_no_good(redir.url):  # ok!
            return redir.url
        else:
            tmp_url = redir.url
    else: # no acceptable responses :(
        return tmp_url
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    return url
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    return redir.headers.get('location', url)
```